# Why do some 12.04 PPAs not work in 12.10?

Tags: software-center, ppa

After a fresh install of Quantal some of the PPAs from Precise don't work.
Even with apps such as Lightread that were recently created and from the Precise Software Centre.

Is there a separate Software Centre for each release?

Do PPAs work across versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PPAs must support each version. If the developers haven't set up their repository for 12.10 yet, it won't work. There are not separate Software Centers for each version, but they do use different repositories on the backend.

The reason for this is fairly simple. Different versions of Ubuntu may require different code for the program to work correctly.